# How to delete one's region in WeChat?

Tags: wechat

In the [Android WeChat messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.mm), it is possible to set up a *region* in one's account settings (*Me* -> tap user name -> *Region*). This region setting is then shown to all contacts in one's profile.

However, once that is done, there does not appear to be an obvious way to unset the region again.

**I would like to remove my *region* setting from my account. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1):

I am a Chinese user and I'm *extremely* sure that:

You **cannot unset** your Region settings in WeChat. You **can only change** it by repeating the procedure in which you set it.

**Edit:** From Chinese BBSs people claim that they succeeded by using an exploit of incompatibility between older and newer versions of WeChat. Their procedure is

1. Install an old enough version of WeChat (They picked 4.2)
2. Change your region settings to anything else
3. Install a newer version of WeChat (They picked 5.2)
4. Due to incompatibility the region is blank

Do note that the posts I've found are in 2015 and even 2014. I'm note sure if WeChat's server still accepts versions other than 6.x

Answer (score -1):

1. Log in to your Wechat.
2. Then, press home button.
3. Go to settings of ur phone.
4. Find wechat and uninstall.
5. Once done,install wechat.

**PS** : *Gender* and *Region* fields will be blank.

Answer (score -2):

To change it:

Me > My Profile (click on the your profile photo) > More > Region

Comment: I don't want to change it, I want to clear the region so there's no region set any more (as it was before I first chose a region).